# Fail install package on Centos 7 with Nexus Sonatype

Tags: centos, nexus, yum

I have 2 server

1. Server Centos 7
2. Nexus Sonatype

When i check centos version it return:

[image]

But, When I try to install any Package of Centos 7, I received an error: "**Depsolving loop limit reached.**"
[image]

**There are no errors that happen when I install CentOS 6 packages.**

How can I handle this error? Or how can I upgrade up repolist for centos 7 with Nexus.